# Creating associative array from object

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, associative

I currently have an array that is building with the correct data by looping an object but it's giving the incorrect format:

```
$priceResult = array();

foreach($prices->categories as $category){ 

    $priceResult[] = $category->category_name;
    $priceResult[] = $category->category_desc;
    $priceResult[] = $category->category_code;

    foreach($category->products as $product){

        $priceResult[] = $product->product_info->item->item_code;

        foreach ($product->product_info->details as $details) {

            $priceResult[] = $details->description;
            $priceResult[] = $details->color;
            $priceResult[] = $details->sector;
        }

        $priceResult[] = $product->product_info->code;
        $priceResult[] = $product->product_info->item->description;
        $priceResult[] = $product->product_info->item->item_type->quantity;

        foreach(get_object_vars($product->prices) as $amount){

            $priceResult[] = $amount;

        }
    }
}
```

This isn't associative though.

So currently, say I have one category with two products then they all print out as a single array

```
array({
    1:category_name
    2:category_desc
    3:category_code
    4:item_code
    5:description
    6:color
    7:sector
    8:code
    9:description
    10:quantity
    11:amount
    12:item_code
    13:description
    14:color
    15:sector
    16:code
    17:description
    18:quantity
    19:amount
})
```

I'd like to get a structure where the parent level is the category_code with it's name and description, then each item_code and their own info like so:

```
array({
    category_name
    category_desc
    category_code
      Array(
       1: item_code array(
            details array(
                description
                color
                sector
            )
            code
            description
            quantity
            amount) 
       2: item_code array(
            details array(
                description
                color
                sector
            )
            code
            description
            quantity
            amount) 
 ) 
})
```

How can I modify this to create the levels like I need so that it formats properly when I export to a spreadsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split you code and init new object in the loop.

Consider the following (notice the comment in the code)

```
$allCategoryResult= array(); // init at first - notice naming as category and not prices

foreach($prices->categories as $category){ 
    $categoryItem = array(); // as current category to populate

    // give name to the keys and not just numbers
    $categoryItem["name"] = $category->category_name; 
    $categoryItem["desc"] = $category->category_desc;
    $categoryItem["code"] = $category->category_code;

    foreach($category->products as $product){
        $productItem = array(); // new product, so init new array for him

        // fill all the item data with name - maybe you will need to fix the paths here
        $productItem["details"] = array(); // init empty array for all the details elements
        foreach ($product->product_info->details as $details) {
            $detailsItem = array(); // init details array for each detail element
            $detailsItem["description"] = $details->description;
            $detailsItem["color"] = $details->color;
            $detailsItem["sector"] = $details->sector;
            $productItem["details"][] = $detailsItem; // add the detail element to the product array
        }

        $productItem["code"] = $product->product_info->code;
        $productItem["itemDescription"] = $product->product_info->item->description;
        $productItem["quantity"] = $product->product_info->item->item_type->quantity;
        $productItem["amount"] = get_object_vars($product->prices);

        $itemCode = $product->product_info->item->item_code;
        categoryItem[$itemCode] = $productItem; // add the product to category array by his code
    }
    $allCategoryResult[] = $categoryItem; //add the category to all category array
}
```

Writing this without see you actual data is pretty hard - so I guess you will have to modify it to fit your data.

But I hop you get the idea. Good luck!

Comment: I think this works but one thing I noticed is that details has 2 sets  for every itemCode. So wouldn't I need another foreach around details?

Comment: Yes - I was not aware of that. You need another for loop - I will updated my post shortly to support it

Comment: Thanks so much for that

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks again

Comment: So this dumps the data structure I want and I export to xlsx it shows each category_name, category_desc, and category_code. However, I was hoping it would do the category data in one row and each associated item (itemCode data) as a row beneath. Will that not work like this?

Comment: I think my question is basically: this puts everything in one array structured how I want , but if I want the category info as a header row for each subsequent item I guess I would have to loop on $allCategoryResult and foreach one assign the itemCode as the key for the next info?

Comment: I think it would be foreach group_code as key, set group info as row, foreach itemCode, start child row

Comment: Is there a way to make the ```$itemCode``` a key in the same way everything else is with quotes? The only thing out of this whole array now that doesn't have quotes around it is the itemCode and I feel like that could solve my problem

Comment: It doesn't have quotes around because its dynamic value. You can add tje itemCode to productItem as all the rest of fields with `"itemCode"` and then when adding to category just use the `[]` but I believe having the key as itemCode is better